# merge pipe die after catchError

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I've trying to use Angular material paginator and sorting, and get some code from material.angular.io example. This part:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDao(this.http);

    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
            this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
        }),
        map(data => {
          // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.total_count;

          return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          // Catch if the GitHub API has reached its rate limit. Return empty data.
          this.isRateLimitReached = true;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

when server return an error and catchError handled it, sorting ang paging stopt to send requests to the server. What's wrong with theirs example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how observable works, in case of onComplete or onError the observable is stopped. If you want it to resume you can add a repeat operator after catchError, your source observable is a hot Observalbe so you don't have to worry about auto infinite loop. Alternatively you can look into `repeatWhen` operator

```
merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = true;
      return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
        this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, 
        this.paginator.pageIndex).pipe(
          map(data => {
             // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
             this.isLoadingResults = false;
             this.isRateLimitReached = false;
             this.resultsLength = data.total_count;
             return data.items;
         }),
          catchError(() => {
             this.isLoadingResults = false;
             this.isRateLimitReached = true;
             return observableOf([]);
          })
        );
    })
  ).subscribe(data => this.data = data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Repeat operator start loopping untill server is return something, but in my case I wont just continue listen sortChange and page, and just after their changes trying get data again from the server.

Comment: so you want to stop the stream when there is data?

Comment: I just wont to try get data from server in some cases: init, sort, paging, filtering. If server return error I've just show notification about that to user. And after that he can continue trying sorting filtering and paging

Comment: Do you get the infinite looping ? I think startWith({}) is messing things up

Comment: I get this code from angular material example https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples I'm new in Angular, TypeScript and RxJs

Comment: The code used in material is not quite right for ideal reactive programmer practise. StartWith will make the stream loop when combine with repeat() because. I have edited the code and it should work without repeat()

Comment: Great to hear that it works. Please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can catch error from within switchMap, this should not kill the merge one.

```
switchMap(() => {
  this.isLoadingResults = true;
  return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
    this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex).pipe(
    catchError(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.isRateLimitReached = true;
      return observableOf([]);
    })
  );
}),
```